# SSRS RowNumber replacement formula not displaying as expected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a strange situation that is baffling me - wonder if anyone can shed some light please?

Using SQL Server Report Builder, I'm creating an educational report based on different criteria for the college where I work, and while most sections of the report will have data, certain sections might not.

I have an expression for replacing cells where there is no data with a zero

```
=IIF(RowNumber("FunctionalSkillsMaths")= 0,0,Fields!ActMathE1.Value)
```

Where the dataset, **FunctionalSkillsMaths** records students that are taking FS courses as part of their higher education.

The problem I'm getting, is that when the cell formula is just the first section, I get a 0 displayed

```
=RowNumber("FunctionalSkillsMaths")
```

but when the formula is as above, I'm left with an empty cell, which isn't suitable.

I've also tried replacing **RowNumber** with **CountRows** and both of these display a zero, but then fail to perform as expected with the IIF replacement.

Table layout...

```
SecRef      ActEngL1WdEngL1 AcEngL1 FlEngL1 ActEngL2

SSA 1.3     16  0   0   0   10
SSA 1.5     8   1   0   0   11
SSA 1.6     28  2   0   0   7
```

Thanks in advance,

Jon

Comment: Can you provide a few rows of sample data, plus how you would want these rows displayed?

Comment: I've added the data into the original post, can't figure how to do it in comments!

For the missing SSA 1.4 record, I'd want to display a row of zeroes.

Comment: Does `SSA 1.4` exist in the DataSet at all? Or should it be included implicitly?

Comment: SSA 1.4 does exist in the wider context of the report, but for this section it contains no data - hence the need to display 0